# Запятая после что (что, пока … , …)

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна помощь с таким предложением, а точнее с его частью: 
«Он сказал, что (,) пока он здесь, нам не о чем волноваться». 
Скажу ещё, что меня здесь волнует именно кусок с «пока». Чаще всего «пока» как раз таки выделяется, но конфуз в том, что в приведённом мною предложении запятая после «что» может стоять в случае, если там деепричастный оборот (коим «пока» не является), или какое-либо другое вводное слово/выражение. Не ручаюсь за достоверность моих мыслей, конечно. 
Ещё замешательство вызывает то, что в моём случае запятая так и просится её поставить, ведь, проговаривая предложение целиком, я чётко выделяю «пока он здесь» паузой. 
Так нужна ли там запятая, или я просто заморачиваюсь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обязательно запятая перед "пока". Там "вставка".

Основа данного предложения:

`Он сказал, что нам не о чем волноваться.`

`пока он здесь` - это дополнительное простое предложение (а не оборот).

Расширим, чтобы запятые стали очевидными:

`Он сказал, что, пока он ещё будет находится здесь, нам не о чем волноваться.`

От увеличения/уменьшения количества слов постановка запятых не меняется.

Причина запятой в том, что слово `что` относится именно к последней части. Но это же предложение можно переделать так, что оно будет относится к средней части и будет без запятой:

`Он сказал, что пока побудет здесь, нам не о чем волноваться.`